# Writing H.264 RTP stream data to a container file

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtp, mkv

In a call, I receive RTP packets (h264 payload). I am trying to depacketize it and write it to a container file like mkv or mp4 using ffmpeg. However the output file is not playing. I am following below steps, please let me know whats wrong here.

1. Got RTP packet
2. Removed RTP header 12 bytes
3. Read one more byte and calculated F, NRI & Type value. Type value comes to 1 most of the time, sometime it is 5 also.
4. Since type is in between 1 & 23, it is of type single NAL unit.
5. Allocates a buffer say BUF.
6. Writes first 3 byte as 0x00 0x00 0x01.
7. Then copy from video payload + 1 offset (since we have read 1 byte as described in point #3) to BUF
8. Use this BUF to prepare avpacket and write this to output file using AV_Write_* API of ffmpeg. This part I have done correctly as it works fine for me in case of vp8 codec.
9. Get the output file.
10. However this file is not playing in ffmpeg.

Please let me know of my approach is correct.

I have observed sometimes group of packets coming with marker bit as 0, with same RTP timestamp. Do I need to concatenate such group of packets and write as single NALU, or each packet I should write as single NALU to output file.

Comment: Do you ensure the packets are processed in order?  Is it an option to let ffmpeg itself do the RTP processing?

Comment: I suggest you read [RFC 6184](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6184) in some detail. If the packetization mode is set to zero then you can use single NAL units. If not, you need to handle STAP and FU packet reconstruction as well.